# Proper way to move data to a data warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I am in the middle of a small project aimed to eventually create a data warehouse. I am currently moving data from a flat file system and two SQL Server databases. The project started in C# to automate the processing of data from the flat file system. Along with this, the project executes stored procedures to bring data from other databases. They are accessing the data from other databases using linked servers.

I am wondering if this is incorrect as even though it does get the job done, there may better approach? The other way I have thought about this is to use the app to pull data from each DB then push it to the data warehouse, but I am not sure about performance. Is there another way? Any path that I can look into is appreciated.

Comment: You can look into ETL processes like Microsofts SSIS (SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES)

Comment: Incorrect is relative term...ETL processes vary heavily

Comment: I suppose when I meant incorrect I was asking if using linked servers is advisable when doing a SQL only data moves.

Comment: Linked servers tends to be the much slower way to do business. Further many dbas  do not alow linked servers to be created due to the potential for performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

'proper' is a pretty relative term.  I have seen a series of stored procedures, SSIS (microsoft), and third party tools.  THey each have some advantages

- Stored procedures
  Using a job to schedule a series of stored procedures that insert rows from one server to the next works.  I find sql developers more likely to take this path...it's flexible in design and good SQL programmers can accomplish nearly anything in here.  That said, it is exceedingly difficult to support / troubleshoot / maintain / alter (especially if the initial developer(s) are no longer with the company).  There is usually very poor error handling here
- SSIS and other tools such as pentaho or data stage or ...google search it, theres a few.
  This gives a more graphical design interface, although I've seen SSIS packages that simply called a stored procedures in order that may as well just been a job. These tools are really what you make of them.  They give very easy to see work flows and are substantially robust when it comes to error handling and troubleshooting ability (trust me, every ETL process is going to have a few bad days and you'll be very happy for any logging you have to identify what you want).  I find configuring a servers resources (multiple processors for example) is significantly easier with these tools.  They all come with quite the learning curve though.

I find SQL developers are very much inclined to use the stored procedure route while people from a DBA background are generally more inclined to use the tools.  If you're investing the time into it, the SSIS or equivlent tool is a better way to go from the future of your company standpoint, though takes a bit more to implement.

Answer (score 1):

In choosing what to use you need to consider the following factors:

How much data are we talking about moving and how quickly does it need to be moved. There is s huge difference between using a linked server to move45,000 records and using it to move 100,000,000 records. Consider alo the expected growth of the data set to be moved over time. A process taht is fine in the early stages may chocke and die once you get more records. Tools like SSIS are much faster once you know how to use them which brings us to point 2.

How much development time do you have and what tools does the developer and the person who will maintain the import over time know? SSIS for instance is a complex tool, it can take a long time to feel comfortable with it.

How much data cleaning and transforming do you need to do? What kind of error trapping and exception processing do you need, what kind of logging will you need? The more complex the process, the more likely you will need to bite the bullet and learn an ETL specific tool.

Answer (score 0):

Even there is a few answers, and I agree with two of them, I have to give my subjective opinion about the wider picture.

> I am in the middle of a small project aimed to eventually create a data warehouse.

Question name perfectly suits to your question description. It could be very helpful to future readers. So, your project should create data warehouse. However it's small, *learn to develop projects with scalability*. Always!

In that point of view, search and study about how data warehouse project should look like. And develop each step.

**Custom software vs Stored Procedures (Linked DBs) vs ETL**

Custom software (in this case your C# project) should be used in two cases:

1. Medium scale projects where budget ETL cannot do everything
2. You're working for Enterprise level IT company, so developing your solution is cheaper and more manageable

And perhaps you think for tiny straight-forward projects. But NO, because those projects can grow and very quick outgrow your solution (new tables, new sources, changing ERP or CRM, ect).

If you're using just SQL Server, if you no need for data cleansing, if you no need for data profiling, if you no need for external data, Stored Procedures are OK. But, a lot of 'ifs' is here. And again, you're loosing scalability (your managment what's to add some data from Google Spreadsheet they internly use, KPI targets for example).

ETL tools are one native step in data warehouse development. In begining, there could be few table copy operation, or some SQL's, one source, one target. As far as your project is growing, you can adding new transformations.

SSIS is perhaps best as you're using SQL Server, but there is some good, free tools.